# FirefoxDriver Cannot start the driver service

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Have an app that has been running without issue (or so Ive been told) for months, but as of a few weeks ago started failing.  Looking at the logs, I see a lot of these errors

> EXCEPTION: Error intializing Firefox driver. Error message: 'Cannot
> start the driver service on http://localhost:52022/';
> WebDriverException stack: 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot
> start the driver service on http://localhost:52022/ at
> OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start() at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
> commandToExecute) at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
> driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities
> desiredCapabilities) at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor
> commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) at ... ... .

The project is a console app that is using the Selenium project to try to connect to an external website but it seems it is having trouble just starting up.  The code where this exception is caught is below.

```
            this._logger = logger;
            this._processLog = new List<string>();

            FirefoxProfile profile = null;
            FirefoxOptions options = null;

            profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadPath);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/json,text/csv");
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.panel.shown", false);

            options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.AddArguments("-headless");
            options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
            options.Profile = profile;

            try
            {
                this._driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverPath, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
            }
            catch (WebDriverException ex)
            {
                string message = string.Format("Error intializing Firefox driver. Error message:  '{0}'; WebDriverException stack:  '{1}' ",
                    ex.Message, ex.ToString());
                result.ProcessLog.Add(new LogMessage(LogLevel.EXCEPTION, message));
                throw ex;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string message = string.Format("Error intializing Firefox driver. Error message:  '{0}'; Exception stack:  '{1}' ",
                    ex.Message, ex.ToString());
                result.ProcessLog.Add(new LogMessage(LogLevel.EXCEPTION, message));
                throw ex;
            }
```

The computer where this process runs has the latest version of Firefox installed, however, the FireFox Selenium driver looks dated.  Could there be a dependency issue?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Selenium version? Geckodriver version?

Comment: geckodriver 0.23.0
WebDriver implementation for Firefox.
Selenium.Webdriver version 3.141.0

Comment: Also, strange that after doing a bit of research, I seen some reference to possible issues with PATH.  I copied the geckodriver.exe into the same path where Firefox is installed and things started working.